# Smooth Parameterization of Set of Linear Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Consider a finite dimensional vector space $V$(with inner product if needed), for example $\mathbb{R}^n$, for $m<n$, I want to give a smooth parameterization of the set of $m$-dimensional subspaces $S$, to make $S$ to be a smooth manifold or something.

Is there a canonical way of doing this, given a basis of the vector space $V$?

Comment: Check Grassmannian: Given $S$, the graphs of linear mappings in $L(S,S^\bot)$ parameterize linear subspaces near $S$.

Comment: That parametrization being, take $T:S\to S^\perp$ to its graph $\{(v,Tv)\ :\ v\in S\}$. (Note that Peter Michor's $S$ is not the original poster's $S$.) And by the way, "a canonical way of doing this" exactly means _not_ "given a basis of the vector space".